# Different between syntax error and parse error

Tags: syntax-error, parse-error

I am wondering that is there any different between parse error and syntax error ? if so can anyone please tell me what is the different ?
thanks

Comment: according to general programming context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand it is that a parse error happens because of a syntax error.  You (the developer) write code that contains a 'syntax error'.  When that code is compiled, the compiler tries to parse your code but cannot which results in a parse error.
If you are dealing with an interpreted language, (PHP, ASP, etc.) the parse error happens when the code is run because it is compiled and run at the same time.